# How to efficiently bundle and debundle many files for transfer and remote processing?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, tar, file-transfer

I wish to repeatedly transfer a fixed set of ~800 files to a remote server to run a recurring task.

The files are of varying sizes (mostly < 1MB, but with several larger ones totalling ~220GB) and file formats (mostly textual).

The task executed on the remote server is within a linux docker container and requires these files to be in their specific relative tree structure.

It is not feasible to transfer them individually or recursively by specifying the directory. Neither is using a volume mount in any way.

**Q: I am searching for a method that allows to bundle these files into a single file such that they can be *de-bundled* and written on the remote server quickly.**

The bundling of the files is not time-critical as this it will not be a repeated task.

**Tar archives**
I tried tar archives, tar.gz at compression level 9 and level 1 with no significant difference in speed. ~30 minutes.

Are there any faster methods I am not aware of?

Comment: you might want consider **not bundling** in the first place. without bundling, you could transfer only the changed files and improve speeds. either way, take a look at [rsync(1)](https://rsync.samba.org/) -- remote file transfer app/protocol that's known for " fast incremental file transfer" that only sends changed data

Comment: Why is it not feasible to transfer them individually/recursively? `scp` or `rsync` should be able to handle 800 files. 800 is really not a lot.